# Matlab plot a fit on GUI axes

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, curve-fitting

I can successfully display data points on my GUI (built with GUIDE).
This is how I do it:

```
t = t_rec(:);
d_PCr = d_PCr_rec(:);
plot(handles.axes_tau, t, d_PCr, 'wo', 'MarkerFaceColor', [0.5 0.5 0.5]);
```

But I'd like to overlay a fit on these data points.
Here's how I fit the data:

```
ok_ = isfinite(t) & isfinite(d_PCr);
if ~all( ok_ )
    warning( 'GenerateMFile:IgnoringNansAndInfs', ...
        'Ignoring NaNs and Infs in data' );
end

st_ = [1.1 1.1 0.0945 ];
ft_ = fittype('a+b*[1-exp(-(x-300)/t1)]',...
    'dependent',{'y'},'independent',{'x'},...
    'coefficients',{'a', 'b', 't1'});

cf_ = fit(t(ok_), d_PCr(ok_), ft_, 'Startpoint', st_);
```

What syntax should I sue to plot this fit on top of my data points?

My **axes_tau** is already on `add`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a 2D fit, it is returned as a [`cfit`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/cfit.html) object. `cfit` can be directly evaluated by the [`feval`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/feval.html) function. Let's say you want to plot a smoother fit than the original data. You can do something as follows to evaluate the returned fit:

```
tf_ = [t(1):((t(end)-t(1))/1000):t(end)]; % 1000 will make it smooth and dense. Pick a number that suits you.
yf_ = feval(cf_, tf_); % Evaluate the fit
plot(handles.axes_tau, tf_, yf_, 'k-');
```

Since the fit object is just a set of coefficients that describes the analytical function you are fitting, you can sample it as coarsely or as finely as you would like. Pick a set of sampling points that give you a smooth looking curve on the screen. In this example, I just made 1001 samples from `t(0)` to `t(end)`.

Comment: thx @mad physicist but the issue is not the use of `hold` (I forgot to mention my axes are on `add` already). My problem is with the syntax of plotting a fit. I can't figure it out, it seems to be different from the syntax of plotting points and I crash the script.

Comment: @torr. Updated. Hopefully, this will help.

Comment: beautiful! works great, thanks so much. How does the smoothing function change my original fit? Would there be a way of passing the fit unchanged to the axes?

Comment: @torr. Check the little blurb I just edited in at the end of the post.